# VNC black screen issue

Tags: vnc

I am trying to access my machine through VNC. The distro that I am using is the SLES 15.1 and is hosted under azure services. The deployed version is the server one and therefore I added the GNOME afterwards. Everything worked fine. Until I try to run the vncserver.

If I do: `sudo vncserver :1` I am able to see the gnome interface as expected from the vnc client. However if I execute `vncserver :1` as a regular user, I see a black screen on the vnc client.

I already tried multiple xstartup files, but without success.

Does anyone know the reason for this to happen and how to fix it?

Maybe I have to modify display manager configuration?

Thank you